# Remote debug binary for QNX target using windows

Tags: remote-debugging, qnx

I want to debug a precompiled and closed-source binary, with QNX x86 as target. The host machine is running win 10 x64.

The binary in question (lets call it hdd) needs a bunch of libraries, which are available in the same dir (/root). If I log in locally to the qnx machine and invoke the ./hdd command, it finds every lib and runs correctly. Later I need it started with some arguments, but my first step is to get it running in the first place. Searching through the documentation, I found a way to specify args. But first things first.

On qnx I run:

```
pdebug 123
```

On my windows machine, I started:

```
C:\qnx660\host\win32\x86\usr\bin\ntox86-gdb.exe
target qnx ip:123
```

So far, so good. But now the troubles start. I serached for hours and hours, but I cannot find a way to tell the system "use the remote dir /root" for working, the binary and all the libs are there. I use set nto-cwd, but then it either crashes due to lack of libraries, or it cannot find the binary on the remote target.

In fact, I am not sure if this is even possible. All the docs and tutorials I found relied on a binary with debug symbols, which I do not have. Furthermore, I am not very experienced with command line debugging, I am used to having at least a minimal gui (like ollyDbg). I have a working trial of qnx momentics, can I use this as well for a minimal gui?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The QNX Momentics has a built-in debugging functionality based on gdb. Start by [creating a launch configuration](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.0.0/index.html#com.qnx.doc.ide.userguide/topic/creating_launch_configuration.html) on debug mode. Select both the binary you want to debug, and the IP address of your QNX target.

When you press the run button, Momentics runs the binary on the target QNX, and you will immediately see the output on the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Try to CD to /root and then start pdebug there. Then in GDB you dont need to cd... This should solve your Problems with loading Libs from /root.